# My redux data is not loading at page load and my mapping function is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am now trying to use useSelector and useDispatch.

The top of the home component look like this

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchGuides} from '../ducks/modules/Articles';

const {windowWidth} = Dimensions.get('window');

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const guideList = useSelector((state) => state.articlesReducer.guideList);

useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        dispatch(fetchGuides());
}[])
```

The data actually comes into this home component but whenever I refresh the page or close server and reopen it.
The mapping function below is giving me an `undefined` error.

The error is something like this `guide.id === undefined`

```
const guideCardGenerator = (guide) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={guide.id}
            onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('GuidesDetails', {
                    screen: 'GuidesDetails',
                    params: {
                        title: guide.title,
                        author: guide.author,
                    },
                })
            }>
            <Card style={styles.guidecard}>
                <View style={styles.guidetextContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.guidetextColor}>Guides</Text>
                </View>
                <Card.Content>
                    <Title>{guide.title}</Title>
                    <Paragraph>{guide.summary}</Paragraph>
                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    let firstGuide = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        guideList && firstGuide.push(guideList[i]);
    }

return (
    <View>{firstGuide && firstGuide.map((guide) => guideCardGenerator(guide))}</View>
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the firstGuide array?  Don’t you just want to map the guideList?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
let firstGuide = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
   guideList && guideList[i] && firstGuide.push(guideList[i]);
}
```